# Config eclipse to view .esp as a jsp file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, sling

I'm working on Apache Sling framework and my Eclipse IDE recognize esp file as a text file, so are there any way to make it work as jsp file so i could have auto complete, highlight effect...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file association in Preferences General > Editors > File Associations.
Here you can add the esp file type and associate it with the jsp editor.

Comment: I'm sorry but It's doesn't work for me in this case.

Comment: Try adding *.esp also in Preferences > General > Content Types. Under Text > JSP add *.esp.

Answer (score 0):

ESP files are not JSPs, they are server-sided Javascript files. Therefore there's no point in configuring an IDE to highlight them as JSPs.